# Weird output of char * with getchar to printf

Tags: c, printf, getchar, cc

I'm dusting off of my C skills for an upcoming class and I came across this weird output with `printf` after building a string using `getchar`. Specifically, any string I try to output gets the same sequence of characters appended to each letter. `foo` becomes `"f?8@{?o?8@{?o?8@{?"` compiling with `cc`, and `f¿:¿o¿:¿0¿:¿` with `Apple LLVM 5.0` (Xcode). Here is the sample code that illustrates the issue:

```
char * input_buffer = malloc( sizeof( char ) );

char c;
while ( ( c = getchar() ) != '\n' ) {
    strcat(input_buffer, &c);
}

// problem output
printf( "\n%s\n", input_buffer );
// foo -> f¿:¿o¿:¿0¿:¿

// weird side effect is the 4 is required to get a proper len
printf("\ncharacters: %lu\n", strlen( input_buffer ) / 4 );
```

I've searched everywhere but I'm not seeing this anywhere else, but then this seems like a bit of an edge case. Is this is some kind of an encoding issue that I am not taking into account?

Comment: you are allocating single character by malloc

Comment: Minor: Use `printf("%zu", strlen( input_buffer ) / 4 );`.  The type returned by `strlen()` is `size_t` and a binary operation (`/`) of `size_t` and `int` will result in a `size_t`.  `'z'` is the matching format specification modifier for the unsigned integer type  `size_t`.

Comment: Why the downvote? Downvoting without explanation isn't terribly helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char * input_buffer = malloc( sizeof( char ) );
```

`sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition. This allocates space for a single character, and makes `input_buffer` point to it.

You're also not checking whether the allocation succeeded. `malloc` returns a null pointer on failure; you should always check for that.

And the allocated `char` object that `input_buffer` points to contains garbage.

```
char c;
while ( ( c = getchar() ) != '\n' ) {
    strcat(input_buffer, &c);
}
```

`getchar()` returns an `int`, not a `char`. You can assign the result to a `char` object, but by doing so you lose the ability to detect and end-of-file or error condition. `getchar()` returns `EOF` when there are no more characters to be read; you should always check for that, and doing so requires storing the result in an `int`. (`EOF` is an integer value that's unequal to any valid character.)

```
    strcat(input_buffer, &c);
```

`input_buffer` points to a single uninitialized `char`. You can treat it as an array consisting of a single `char` element. The first argument to `strcat` must already contain a valid null-terminated string, and it must have enough space to hold that string plus whatever you're appending to it.

`c` is a single `char` object, containing whatever character you just read with `getchar(). The second argument to`strcat`is a`char*`, so you've got the right type -- but that`char*` must point to a valid null-terminated string.

`strcat` will first scan the array pointed to by `input_buffer` to find the terminating `'\0'` character so it knows where to start appending -- and it will probably scan into memory that's not part of any object you've declared or allocated, possibly crashing your program. If that doesn't blow up, it will then copy characters starting at `c`, and going past it into memory that you don't own. You have multiple forms of undefined behavior.

You don't need to use `strcat` to append a single character to a string; you can just assign it.

Here's a simple example:

```
char input_buffer[100];
int i = 0; /* index into input_buffer */
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
    input_buffer[i] = c;
    i ++;
}
input_buffer[i] = '\0'; /* ensure that it's properly null-terminated */
```

I allocated a fixed-size buffer rather than using `malloc`, just for simplicity.

Also for simplicity, I've omitted any check that the input doesn't go past the end of the input buffer. If it does, the program may crash *if you're lucky*; if you're not lucky, it may just appear to work while clobbering memory that doesn't belong to you. It will work ok if the input line isn't too long. In any real-world program, you'll want to check for this.

BTW, what's being done here is more easily done using `fgets()` -- but it's good to learn how things work on a slightly lower level.

Comment: All of the examples I found used `char arr[]` for the string, but that requires my knowing how long the longest string would be, and for this exercise I don't. So, why not just use `char *` and what would be used to append to the `char *`? I know at a certain level they are the same thing, but I would think not having to manage the bounds of the array would be better.

Comment: @PhilipRegan: With a `char*`, you still have to know the maximum length; the difference is that you can determine it at run time. You can use `realloc` to expand the array (actually to replace the array by a larger one) as needed. You'd append single characters the same way. (BTW, arrays and pointers are not the same thing on any level; see section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www-c.faq.com).)

Comment: "...arrays and pointers are not the same thing on any level..." Sorry, I'm not explaining myself very well here. Thanks for the answer. Very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot call `strcat(input_buffer, &c);`.

Each of the arguments passed to `strcat` must be a valid null-terminated string of characters.

The chances of the next byte after `&c` being 0 are pretty slim.

The chances of the first byte pointed by `input_buffer` being 0 aren't very high either.

In other words, `strcat` reads "junk" until it encounters a 0 character, **in both arguments**.

**Change:**

```
while ( ( c = getchar() ) != '\n' ) {
    strcat(input_buffer, &c);
}
```

**To:**

```
for (int i=0; 1; i++)
{
    c = getchar();
    if (c == '\r' || c == '\n')
    {
        input_buffer[i] = 0;
        break;
    }
    input_buffer[i] = c;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to check for `'\r'`. `stdin` is a text stream, so a line ending (whether it's a UNIX-style LF or a Windows-style CR-LF sequence) is translated to a single `'\n'` newline character. Also, you can omit the `true` in the `for` loop: `for (int i = 0; ; i++)`. (`true` isn't defined anyway unless you've defined it yourself, or you have `#include <stdbool.h>`, or you're using a C++ compiler to compile C code.)

Comment: Are you sure about the '\r'? Had that problem recently (although I was using `getch` from `conio.h`).

Comment: @barakmanos: Yes, I'm sure. I don't know how `getch` from `<conio.h>` behaves; I'm talking about standard C I/O functions.

Comment: @chux: Hi. What's wrong with it being inside the loop, just before the `break`?

Comment: For `strcat` would it make sense to make `c` into a null-terminated string (which seems wasteful to me)? If not, then what to use to append `c` to `input buffer`?

Comment: You won't be able to "getchar into a null-terminated string". Please see the solution suggested in my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

- You are allocating space to `input_buffer` for only one `char`.
- `strcat(input_buffer, &c);` is wrong. You are concatenating character (it is not null terminated) with a string.
- `getchar` returns `int` type but you declared `c` is of type `char`.

Comment: `strcat` does take the address of a `char` as its second argument. The problem is that the `char` needs to be the first character of a string.

Comment: According to documentation `getchar()` returns `unsigned char` casted to `int` or `EOF`. So there is nothing really wrong with that except that `EOF` may get out of `char` range.

Comment: @ony: And that's the problem. By assigning the result of `getchar()` to a `char` object, you lose the ability to detect an end-of-file or error condition.

Comment: For `strcat` would it make sense to make `c` into a null-terminated string (which seems wasteful to me)? If not, then what to use to append `c` to `input buffer`?